# How can I bind function with object in Ruby Shoes GUI?

Tags: ruby, shoes

How can I call addition only when I press enter **and** `@e_ln1` is in focus? If I click enter while `@e_ln2` is in focus, addition in `@e_ln1` is also performed but I don't want it.

```
Shoes.app do

    @e_ln1 = edit_line(width: 150, height: 20)
    @e_ln2 = edit_line(width: 150, height: 20, left: 0, top: 60)

   keypress do |k|
        if k == "\n" 
            @e_ln1.text = @e_ln1.text.to_i + 1
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Shoes3.3.1 there is a finish event on edit_line

```
Shoes.app do
    @e_ln1 = edit_line(width: 150, height: 25)
    @e_ln2 = edit_line(width: 150, height: 25, left: 0, top: 60)

    @e_ln1.finish = proc { @e_ln1.text = @e_ln1.text.to_i + 1 }
end
```

just hit enter in the edit_line of interest to trigger it

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as far as I'm aware as of now in both Shoes 3 and Shoes 4. In Shoes 4 there's even a bug where we don't get keypresses while there is focus on an input field. Sorry :-/

I don't have Shoes 3 running right now, but you could see and check if the "\n" arrives in the input field and check based on that.

Otherwise I opened a Shoes 4 issue to [implement a `focussed?` method](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/1224)